# Stop click event propagation

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to highlight any DOM element of a certain Web page when the user clicks on it. For that purpose, I iterate through all elements of the current element and disable any functionality (so e.g. I can click and not to be redirected):

```
var elems = window.document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].onclick = function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

The thing is, when user clicks, a lot of click events are fired, because every element has tas behaviour, and I need to avoid unhighlight.

Any idea of how to improve that or any alternative?
Thanks a lot!

P/d: It has to be pure JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do two things: first of all, you want to actually add an `event`, not redefine its click behaviour, and secondly, uou want it to not `bubble` up through the dom. Try this:

```
var elems = window.document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    // Use addEventListener to listen for events.
    // Older version of IE use attachEvent, but I guess thats irrelevant.
    elems[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // Use stopImmediatePropagation to stop the element from passing this click to wrapping parents - because a click on a child is technically a click on the parent as well.
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
}
```

Heres more to read:

> Add Event Listener: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
>
> Stop Immediate Propagation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation

As a brave editor says, you can also pass `false` as a third argument to the `addEventListener` and it does basically the same thing but is less comprehensible and does some additional things as well, so I have opted not to default to this just because its easier to understand that you are stopping propagation.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about stopImmediatePropagation! And I use onclick to intentionally override all element behaviour, if not, e.g. insthead of highlighting I just click and get out of that page

Comment: @gal007 `e.preventDefault()` already cancels any other element behaviour, I think the default `onclick` function is just faster since its written in native code, and overwriting it replaces it with slower JS. It will work, but this is really better practise.

Answer (score 1):

I made a jsfiddle that does it:

https://jsfiddle.net/zgqpnaey/

```
var elems = window.document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    myFunction(elems[i]);
}

function myFunction(element) {
     element.onclick = function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
        element.style.background = 'red';
    };    
}
```

somethinghere explained it above.

Also, you shouldn't bind onclick inside a loop, it's known to cause errors; it's better to call a function and pass the proper parameters.