# Stop click from propagating to a parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When a particular element is clicked, I want to call a function.  When any of its children are clicked, I do **not** want to call the function.

I am *not* using jQuery.

**Example:**

I created a modal:

```
<div class="fullscreen-overlay">
  <div class="card">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to call my `closeModal()` function when ".fullscreen-overlay" is clicked, but not when ".card" or any of its content are clicked.

**jsfiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/5kuwmf9s/

**Research:**

I could've sworn there was a CSS attribute for this, but after Googling and searching on SO for it, I can't find it / might've been imagining it. "pointer-events" stops it on the target element, not bubbling.

Theres another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099074/stop-click-event-propagation) that suggests attaching an event handler to ALL children that catches their events and stops propagation - which seems unnecessary.  My children are dynamic, and this will get complicated to keep attaching handlers.

Comment: CSS `z-index` is your solution.

Comment: Nah, z-index doesn't solve it, the events are still propagated up the DOM.

Comment: Can't you just put the "cards" outside the overlay div?

Comment: Logically, it is impossible because `.card` is a part of of `.fullscreen-overlay`, recall Venn's shapes. The only thing, I think, avialble is to make `.fullscreen-overlay` in higher level of its children using `z-index`

Comment: You can also check for the event target at the beggining of the `closeModal()` function, and if it's a card just return

Comment: @MarkE now there's using your noodle with putting the card outside - let me try that.  The checking event would work well if I check if it's an overlay, let me try that too. Checking a card you can't have dynamic children, you'd have to check for all of them too.

Comment: Cannot you compare `e.target` and `e.currentTarget`?

Comment: Do you want it to not get the event *at all*, or just be able to not execute most of the event handler code if it is not `.fullscreen-overlay`?

Comment: @Makyen either one is fine. just don't want to close the modal when the card is clicked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have compared event's `target` and `currentTarget`

They would be equal only if the current element is the one that was the initial source of the event:

```
function handleClick(e){
  if (e.target === e.currentTarget) {
    alert('clicked!');
  }
}
```

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u78k4k6t/

Answer (score 0):

- try use an element and style it as your '.fullscreen-overlay' and bind event to this element
- as the answer link shows
- use event.target or event.srcElement

Comment: Sorry Yanjun - I can't understand what you are saying :(

Comment: there are many ways, the answer zerkms given is the third one in my answer.